# Getting "cannot find symbol" when trying to add label

Tags: codenameone

I have used System.out.println() to verify my search is returning the index to the container on the grid I need, and that .getComponentAt(the returned index) is returning the correct container as Shai told me it would, but I cannot get the .add(label) to work. I am getting the cannot find symbol error when I build the class. I am just working on the first search and place before adding the remainder of the searches to the code. I have also tried to use this.add(label) on the line after I get the container, which builds without error, but the added player does not show on the form when revalidated. Thanks for any ideas.

```
    public boolean movePlayers() {
       slocf = lwtx; // Search String set to textfield entry on form
       LocCel(slocf);{// Search through 204 containers to find and return index value
           lwloc = floc; // location for label returned from LocCel() and assigned ti first player
           if (lw1.isSelected()) { // If player is to have ball, checkbox is checked on form                                                                            
               bC.getComponentAt(lwloc).add(lbllwB); //to access container at index returned from LocCel() and add ball label
            }else {
               bC.getComponentAt(lwloc).add(lbllw);// add player without ball label if does not get ball                                                
            }
        }
        scrn.revalidate();
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What type are you expecting `bc.getComponentAt(lwloc)` to be?  Are you quite sure it will be a container?

Comment: Use `Log.p` not `System.out.println`. This code won't compile. `Component` which is returned by `getComponentAt` doesn't have an `add` method. Also you open a block for no reason on the 3rd line.  Also notice that a component can only be added to one `Container`, this will fail in runtime otherwise... You will need separate instances of the component for adding to multiple containers.

Comment: bC.getComponentAt(lwloc) identifies the empty container the label is moving to. I am working with 20 labels showing different players with and without the ball. The rest of the 204 containers on bC will be empty. My problem is getting the add(label) to work for the Container found in the search. I know the search works because I found the correct Container index, and I could add the correct label as Component 205 in the bC Container. It does not seem that getComponentAt() brings the correct Container into focus so using this.add(label) on the following line would work so I need a way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, Shai. I will clean up the extra block. My other thought is if I getName() of the container after finding it by the index, can I then add(label) using the String name getName() returns?

Comment: `add` will only work  like this `((Container)bC.getComponentAt(lwloc)).add(lbllwB);` since [getComponentAt](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Container.html#getComponentAt-int-) returns `Component` which doesn't have the `add` method. Even if the runtime component is a `Container`, Java won't do the casting implicitly. `getName()` will only work if you set the name on the component previously. In which case it will work.

Comment: Thank you, Shai. The addition you supplied moved the player. Now I will tackle the next part.